# Into which vritti does the swapna avastha fall into?

Tags: yoga, avastha

Chitta has five [vrittis](http://www.ramakrishnavivekananda.info/vivekananda/volume_1/raja-yoga/concentration_its_spiritual_uses.htm). Praman, viparya, vikalpa, nidra and smriti.

Nidra and praman vrittis do not contain a Swapna state. And I'm believing that the Swapna state does not fall into viparya also. Then to which vritti do the sleep state of a human falls into?

Comment: You are confusing 4 states of person with that of scriptures the question is wrong

Comment: @PrasannaR Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I mean, chitta is in which vritti when a person is in swapna avasta.

Comment: Vishwa Taijasa  pragya and turiya are the different states of consciousness that a hunan beign can have Taijasa is sleep state chitaa is memory shell like ram in computer

Comment: May be this memory shell can be calsified yo hold this six details of scriptures not sleep state